# Bootstrapping a Kubernetes cluster using Kubeadm on RHEL 7 - Issues with firewall

Tags: iptables, redhat, ansible, kubernetes, kubeadm

I'm trying to bootstrap a Kubernetes cluster on RHEL 7.8 but I'm having some issues with my firewall.

`nftables` is [not supported](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/71305) in Kubernetes and `iptables-legacy` must be installed instead. While the `iptables-legacy` package exists in distros like Debian Buster, it does not seem to be available for RHEL 7. However, [this article](https://medium.com/@pkp.plus/installing-kubernetes-on-centos-7-rhel7-with-kubeadm-step-by-step-c55acac03590) mentions installing `iptables-services`, disabling `firewalld`, and enabling `iptables`. The relevant material from the article is:

```
yum install iptables-services.x86_64 -y
systemctl stop firewalld.service
systemctl disable firewalld.service
systemctl mask firewalld.service
systemctl start iptables
systemctl enable iptables
systemctl unmask iptables
iptables -F
service iptables save
```

After this, if I run `iptables --version` on the server, I can see that `1.4.2` is installed. Since this is older than 1.8 as implied by the GitHub issue linked above, this version should be fine.

Before running `kubeadm join` from my worker nodes, the following Ansible tasks run against my master to configure `iptables`:

```
- iptables:
    chain: INPUT
    destination_port: "{{ port }}"
    jump: ACCEPT
    protocol: tcp
  loop:
    - 6443
    - 2379:2380
    - 10250:10252
  loop_control:
    loop_var: port

- command: service iptables save

- systemd:
    name: iptables
    state: restarted
```

And this against my nodes to configure `iptables`:

```
- iptables:
    chain: INPUT
    destination_port: "{{ port }}"
    jump: ACCEPT
    protocol: tcp
  loop:
    - 10250
    - 30000:32767
  loop_control:
    loop_var: port

- command: service iptables save

- systemd:
    name: iptables
    state: restarted
```

After this, I can confirm that the rule is present in memory:

```
$> iptables -S | grep 6443
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6443 -j ACCEPT
```

Then, when I run `kubeadm join` from the worker node, it fails to connect:

```
I0406 22:07:19.205714    5715 token.go:73] [discovery] Created cluster-info discovery client, requesting info from "https://192.168.50.10:6443"
I0406 22:07:19.206720    5715 token.go:78] [discovery] Failed to request cluster info: [Get https://192.168.50.10:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info?timeout=10s: dial tcp 192.168.50.10:6443: connect: no route to host]
I0406 22:07:19.206749    5715 token.go:191] [discovery] Failed to connect to API Server "192.168.50.10:6443": Get https://192.168.50.10:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info?timeout=10s: dial tcp 192.168.50.10:6443: connect: no route to host
I0406 22:07:24.207648    5715 token.go:188] [discovery] Trying to connect to API Server "192.168.50.10:6443
```

However, if I `systemctl stop iptables` on the master then the worker nodes can join without any issues. Indicating to me that the firewall on the master is misconfigured?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your issue, could you confirm what kubernetes version did you deployed? You deployed it with kubeadm like the guide on medium you mention in your question?

Comment: V1.18. Deployed according to the official kubeadm docs. https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ansible module `iptables` uses the `append` action by default. This caused the `reject` rules to not be located where they should be. Adding `action: insert` to my `iptables` tasks in Ansible resolved the issue.